# sqlite query to remove a database table

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

why wont the following code remove the table

```
SQLite.TableMapping map = new TableMapping(typeof(SqlDbType)); 
            object[] ps = new object[0]; 

     if (database.Table<Order>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        database.Query(map, "DELETE Order", ps); 
                        database.Query(map, "VACUUM", ps); 
                    }
```

it crashes on the line database.Query(map, "DELETE Order", ps); with exception

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: near "Order": syntax error
```

Comment: 'Order' is a keyword in SQLite

Comment: it's not ``Drop Table order`` to  remove table?

Answer (score 0):

I didn‘t Test it, but I think the query should be `DROP TABLE "Order";`

Thanks to Shawn in the comments below. :)

Comment: `DROP TABLE "Order";`

Comment: @John Yes, this is the right answer. Can you please mark it so that we can help more people with same problem:).